# Read string as integers? (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, csv

I'm new to Python and I'm pretty much just learning things as I go.

I'm trying to import data from an Excel file into my Python program. I need to be able to do simple calculations with these numbers within the Python program rather than Excel. This is how the code looks now:

```
    import csv
    with open ('vals.csv','rb') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        x = next(reader)
        y = next(reader)
        z = next(reader)

        print x[0]+z[2]
        print x[0]+1
```

The first print statement should give me 7 (because the first x is 3 and the third z is 4). Instead it prints 34, so I'm assuming it isn't treating the values as integers?

The second print statement causes this error:

```
    TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

So based on that, I guess it's reading the each row as a string instead of integers. I tried doing this next thing to see if this would convert it to integers:

```
    x = next(reader)
    x = int(x)
    y = next(reader)
    y = int(y)
    z = next(reader)
    z = int(z)
```

But it gives me this error:

```
    TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
```

So I guess it's not reading it as a string?

I just want to know how I can make it read something like x[0] (and all the rest of them) as an integer so I can do calculations with it.

Answer (score 0):

`csv.reader` module yields a list of rows of strings at each iteration.

That is, even if there's only one column per row or if the data contains integers.

To get a list of integers at each row do it in a list comprehension:

```
row1 = [int(x) for x in next(reader)]
```

or since it's python 2:

```
row1 = map(int,next(reader))
```

then use `row1[2]` to access 3rd element of the row as integer.

Answer (score 0):

The [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader) is an iterable of `lists` of strings corresponding to the columns in the row:

```
x = next(reader)
# x: ['3', '4', '5']
```

If all values can be converted to `int`, you can do:

```
x = map(int, x)
# x: [3, 4, 5]
```

Otherwise, you'd have to convert the fields individually:

```
x[0] = int(x[0])
```